# How to get an element in WrappedArray: result of Dataset.select("x").collect()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a beginer on Spark/Scala. I would like to extract a value(Double) in the Array selected from Dataset. Simplified major steps are shown below. How can I extract each value[Double] in the
last val wpA ? Something like val p1 = wpA(1). I failed to conver it to normal array by wpA.toArray.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
case class Event(eventId: Int, n_track: Int, px:ArrayBuffer[Double],py: ArrayBuffer[Double], pz: ArrayBuffer[Double],ch: ArrayBuffer[Int], en: ArrayBuffer[Double])
---
val rawRdd =  sc.textFile("expdata/rawdata.bel").map(_.split("\n"))
val eventRdd = rawRdd.map(x => buildEvent(x(0).toString))
val dataset = sqlContext.createDataset[Event](eventRdd) 
dataset.printSchema()
    root
      |-- eventId: integer (nullable = false)
      |-- n_track: integer (nullable = false)
      |-- px: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
      |-- py: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
      |-- pz: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
      |-- ch: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
      |-- en: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)

val dataFrame  = dataset.select("px")     
val dataRow =  dataFrame.collect()      
val wpA = dataRow(1)(0)  
println(wpA)
      WrappedArray(-0.99205, 0.379417, 0.448819,.....)
```

Answer (score 8):

When you write:

```
val wpA = dataRow(1)(0)
```

You get a variable of type `Any`, because `org.apache.spark.sql.Row.apply(Int)` (which is the method called here on the result of `datarow(1)`), returns `Any`.

Since you know the expected type of the first item (index = 0) of this row, you should use `Row.getAs[T](Int)` and indicate that you expect a `WrappedArray`. Then, compiler will know that `wpA` is an array and you'll be able to use any of its methods (including the `apply` method that takes an int and can be called using parens only):

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val wpA = dataRow(1).getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0)
println(wpA) // WrappedArray(-0.99205, 0.379417, 0.448819,.....)
println(wpA(0)) // -0.99205
```

Comment: It's all about [mutable.WrappedArray[Double]](0) . Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @Tzach Zohar. Your solution really helped me as well